# Not understanding F# error message: The type 'Candle.Volumes -> Totals' is not compatible with the type 'Totals'

Tags: f#

I have the following message:

> The type 'Candle.Volumes -> Totals' is not compatible with the type 'Totals'

Totals is type:

```
type Totals = {
    VolumeBeforePrice : int64
    Volume : int64
    ContractsCount : float
}
```

The error is on:

```
    let aggregatedAsks = CalculatePriceAtBaseVolume asks
    let volume = aggregatedAsks.Volume
```

(on the let volume line)

and the function called is:

```
let CalculatePriceAtBaseVolume (entries : OrderBook.Entry list) (minVolume : Candle.Volumes) : Totals =
    let volumeRequested = Candle.ConvertVolumes(minVolume)

    let zero =
        {   VolumeBeforePrice = 0L
            Volume = 0L
            ContractsCount = 0. }

    let aggregation = calculateTotals volumeRequested zero entries
    aggregation : Totals
```

Coming from the C family, I don't understand what 'Candle.Volumes -> Totals' means as it doesn't look like a type, but a function transforming x into y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CalculatePriceAtBaseVolume` takes two arguments and has type

```
OrderBook.Entry list -> Candle.Volumes -> Totals
```

F# functions are curried so the result of applying a single argument results in another function of one argument. You have only provided one argument of type `OrderBook.Entry list` so

```
CalculatePriceAtBaseVolume asks
```

has type `Candle.Volumes -> Totals`.

The expression `aggregatedAsks.Volume` requires `aggregatedAsks` to have type `Totals` but it has type `Candle.Volumes -> Totals` as the type error indicates.

Comment: So if I understand well, one argument is missing and that turns the value into a curried function rather than its return type; is that correct?

Comment: @Thomas - `CalculatePriceAtBaseVolume` is a curried function so technically has a single argument which when applied returns another function of a single argument i.e. `OrderBook.Entry list -> (Candle.Volumes -> Totals)`. If you define a function and don't supply all the declared arguments the result is another function.

Comment: @Thomas - If you're unfamiliar with currying, https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/thinking-functionally.html has an excellent explanation. Currying is explained in the fifth article, but it's wise to read them in order because later articles build on concepts introduced in earlier ones. Then go ahead and bookmark that (excellent) site, because you'll be wanting to refer back to it often as you learn F#.